# no icon is shown and error message shown in the console

Tags: android

```
[2014-11-18 10:26:16 - MyFirstApp] D:\Android_tools\Eclipse IDE\New folder\MyFirstApp\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

[2014-11-18 10:26:18 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file D:\Android_tools\Eclipse IDE\New folder\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-11-18 10:26:18 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file D:\Android_tools\Eclipse IDE\New folder\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
```

The graphical layout is totally different without icon of the app..need to find the solution of the error shown above.
thanks

Comment: you need to set AppCompact library. Right Click on Project -> Properties-> Android-> Add Library->Choose AppCompact-> OK

Comment: nice working.......thank u

Answer (score 0):

> File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose
>   "appcompat"
>            Project-> properties->Android. In the section library "Add" and choose "appCompat"